# Specifying specific priors for a correlation matrix via Stan

Tags: bayesian, factor-analysis, stan

I'm trying to estimate a correlation matrix for a model where I already have a sense of the values of the off-diagonals based on existing studies. I'm quite new to Bayesian analysis so trying to learn as I go along.

The Stan package is pretty bullish on using an LKJ prior for correlation matrices ([see here](https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_25/reference-manual/correlation-matrix-transform-section.html)). There isn't a way for me to encode a specific expected value of the correlation matrix into the prior. From my understanding I could use the inverse Wishart to generate a covariance matrix instead, but that isn't guaranteed to generate a correlation matrix (i.e. diagonal of 1).

Can anyone recommend the best approach here? If it's useful at all I'm trying to recreate [exactly this example](https://michaeldewittjr.com/resources/stan_cfa.html), except specify my prior knowledge about the correlation matrix.

Answer (score 1):

The Stan documentation and examples often use the LKJ prior in situations that are unlike the one you are describing where you are pretty sure about the off-diagonals.

In the case of a confirmatory factor analysis, I would do Wishart or inverse-Wishart on the covariance (not correlation) among the factors and fix some of the loadings to be $1.0$, rather than fixing the factor variances to be $1.0$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider that your covariance matrix $\Sigma$ can be written as a correlation matrix $R$ multiplied elementwise by the tensor product of the vectors of the standard deviations.

$\Sigma = (\vec \sigma \otimes \vec \sigma) \odot R$

Provided that none of the standard deviations are zero, the elementwise product is invertible to obtain:

$(\vec \sigma \otimes \vec \sigma)^{-1} \odot \Sigma = R.$

As suggested by Ben, I would try an inverse-Wishart (or the Wishart up to an inverse) to allow putting background knowledge into the prior. Furthermore, I would try making it adaptive using the above relation so that published correlation values can be used.